# Dynamically populate user input corresponding json data with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a json data that is like this,

```
 [
    {
        "metalTypeId": 1,
        "metalTypeName": "copper"
    },
    {
        "metalTypeId": 3,
        "metalTypeName": "steel"
    }
]
```

My html is structured like this:

```
 <table id="lineItemTable">
 <tr class="row_to_clone">
     <td>
          <select>
              <option>Select One Option</option>
              <option>copper</option>
              <option>steel</option>
          </select>
      </td>

      <td>
          <p></p>
      </td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="row_to_clone">
     <td>
          <select>
              <option>Select One Option</option>
              <option>copper</option>
              <option>steel</option>
          </select>
      </td>

      <td>
          <p></p>
      </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

What I want to do is when the user select one of the options in the dropdown, I want to populate the corresponding `json` data to the `p` tag in my `td`. And my table contains two identical rows.

So for example, if user select copper for the first table row, and select steel for the second table row, the corresponding `p` will populate text "1" and "3" to the html page. If user do not select both rows, only the row that is selected will populate corresponding data to the `p` tag.

I am green to jQuery so I wrote some js code but it does not work as expected:
the variable that stores the `json` data is named as `jasonData`:

```
$('select').on('change', function (e){

           $.each(jasonData, function(i, v) {
                if (jasonData.metalTypeName == $('select').val()) {
                           $('p').text(v.metalTypeId);
                           return;
                }
           }); //end each()

});  // end on()
```

By looking at my code I already know one issue, the `p` and `select` select both two table row fields, but I do not know how to correctly fix it. The code may have other issues, please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is very close to working.  You just need to cache the active `select` when it triggers the `change` event so you can reference it later; compare the active object in your `each` (you were incorrectly referencing the whole array); and use a few selectors to find the right paragraph.  However, you may want to consider using something closer to David's answer.  It's a bit cleaner than this method.

```js
var jasonData = [
  {
    "metalTypeId": 1,
    "metalTypeName": "copper"
  },
  {
    "metalTypeId": 3,
    "metalTypeName": "steel"
  }
];

$('select').on('change', function (e){
  var selected = this;
  $.each(jasonData, function(i, v) {
    if (v.metalTypeName === selected.value) {
      $(selected).closest('.row_to_clone').find('p').text(v.metalTypeId);
      return;
    }
  }); //end each()
});  // end on()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="lineItemTable">
 <tr class="row_to_clone">
     <td>
          <select>
              <option>Select One Option</option>
              <option>copper</option>
              <option>steel</option>
          </select>
      </td>

      <td>
          <p></p>
      </td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="row_to_clone">
     <td>
          <select>
              <option>Select One Option</option>
              <option>copper</option>
              <option>steel</option>
          </select>
      </td>

      <td>
          <p></p>
      </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend you not to use selectors so general such as "select" and "p"; while you are expanding your code, you'll get into issues because of these so generalized; I recommend you using some classes to help you or ID's.
Also, if you can change the structure of that JSON you won't need to do that each, basically you're forcing a O(n) problem there when you can something easier.
Here's an example I wrote for you doing the functionality that you want

http://jsfiddle.net/6v4zzgjj/

Now, if you want to make the selection of the results easier you can try the following

```
//Rename this variable better IE jsonData;
var jasonData = {"copper": { "metalTypeId": 1,"metalTypeName": "copper"}, "steel": {"metalTypeId": 3,"metalTypeName": "steel"}};
//Now the selector could be something like
$('.metalSelector').on('change', function (e){
     var value = $(this).val();
     $('#result').text(jasonData[value].metalTypeId);
});
```

That easy!

Comment: I tried your code but seems it only works with one table row? I want both rows working tho.